# JmsTemplate synchronous receive

Tags: spring-jms

How the jmstemplate receive() method is synchronized? Sender send message to a broker and on the other side consumer consumes message from broker queue or a topic. For receive, it will be some polling thread waiting for some data on a broker. How the synchronization then gets maintained?

Comment: When receive() blocks to wait for a message, does it continue polling the queue, or does it count only one poll per blocking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JmsTemplate` uses the JMS API behind the scene and in particular the `MessageConsumer`. That service can either attempt to receive a `Message` without waiting (`receiveNoWait`) or it can wait a configurable amount of time (`receive(long timeout)`). When it's being invoked with a timeout of 0, the receive method blocks until a message arrives. There's nothing in `JmsTemplate` that deals with all this (i.e. it is provided by the client broker implementation).

A more regular way of receiving messages is to use a listener container. With Spring, the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` allows you to use a thread poll to process incoming messages. Check the [jms documentation of the Spring framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html) for more information.